# VBA - How to remove empty cell from array

Tags: arrays, vba

I've got a range that I'm inserting into an array.
after that, I'm trying to get only the unique Items but I get them with one (unique) empty value (There are few blanks in my range).

**How can I get rid of the empty array cell?**

This is my code:

```
Sub uniqueArray()

Dim myList As Variant
uniqueNameList As Variant

myList = Range("C2:C100").Value
uniqueNameList = WorksheetFunction.Unique(myList)

End sub
```

for example:
[image]

Comment: If you have 365 version you could also use the build in =unique function.

Comment: Got to do it with VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub remBlanks()
        Dim arr, arr2, nrRw As Long
        nrRw = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row - 1 'count source to arr without header
        arr = Sheet2.Range("C2:C" & nrRw).Value2 'add source to arr without header
        
        Dim j As Long, jj As Long: jj = 1
        ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(j, 1) <> "" Then 'remove blanks
                arr2(jj, 1) = arr(j, 1)
                jj = jj + 1
            End If
        Next j
        With Sheet2
            .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(UBound(arr2), 4)).Value2 = arr2 'dumb to sheet
        End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add second function to check for empty value and remove it, like following:

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 100
    If IsEmpty(cells(i,3).Value) Then
    Cells(i, 3).Delete
    End If
Next
```

However, it will be better to check for used row in the sheet to optimize the function.

Comment: That's not helping me because the work was done with the for loops on Excel cells and not with VBA arrays.

Comment: VBA array is referring to excel cells.... . In your case Range("C2:C100"), is equal to cells(2,3) untill cells(100,3), to delete the row, you need break the range into for loop, then should be able to solve your problem...